# authentication protocol refused when using MySQLWorkbench version 6.3

Tags: mysql-workbench

There are many posts here and all over the web about getting the message:

> Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

when trying to connect a a MySQL database. In my case, it's coming from MySQLWorkbench version 6.3 newly installed on a almost as newly install Ubuntu 15.10 system.

The advice is always to update the password on the database to use the new authentication.

However, that is not my problem, and that's not what the message says. It says that the OLD authentication is being used when the database wants the NEW authentication.

This version of MySQLWorkbench has a checkbox that tells it to use the OLD authentication, which is unchecked, but, from the message, it appears to be using the OLD authentication all the time.

I can connect to the database easily from version 5.2 of MySQLWorkbench running on Mac OS X.

I tried installing an older version of MySQLWorkbench on my Ubuntu system, but there were numerous errors with the package, which is intended for an earlier version of Ubuntu.

Any ideas about how I can force MySQLWorkbench to use the NEW authentication? I tried setting:

> useLegacyAuth=0

but that did nothing.

Comment: Maybe it's just a confusing error message? Did you try to set the password for that user again? In the next version of MySQL Workbench (same with the CLI) you no longer can use old auth anyway. The client lib simply no longer supports it.

Comment: Right about the confusing error message. See my answer below. Kicking out the old protocol for good will be nice. The world is confused enough already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got the answer. The hosting outfit (Siteground) sets up MySQL passwords to work with EITHER the legacy or the new protocol. I don't know if this is homegrown, some sort of plugin that's generally available, or a standard MySQL feature. With this option, MySQLWorkbench fails to connect and erroneously reports the problem as the server not supporting the old protocol. Probably it's just confused by the error response which its programmers didn't anticipate.

Siteground very quickly set my password to use the new authentication ONLY upon my request, and then MySQLWorkbench connected with no problem.